# How I could modify a image by zooming in and out?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript

I have a gallery-like component, and the important part is:

```
       

     <Gallery>
      <Header>
        <img src={galleryIcon} alt='Galley icon' />
        <h1>My Gallery</h1>
      </Header>
      <Images isImage={custom.length > 0}>
        {custom.length > 0 &&
          custom.map((c, i) => (
            <img
              id={`custom${i}`}
              key={`custom${i}`}
              src={c.img}
              alt='brick'
              onClick={() => (setEdit((prev) => !prev), setActual(c))}
            />
          ))}
        <div className='add'>
          <button onClick={() => setGallery((prev) => !prev)}>
            <img src={add} alt='Add icon' />
          </button>
          <p>Click to add a brick from our collections!</p>
        </div>
      </Images>
    </Gallery>
```

Each image have this style:

```css
img {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 28vh;
    width: 28vh;
    margin-right: 1.5rem;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

Also, once the user input a new image I resize to no break the scale, with this function:

```
export function resizeImage(
  file: File | Blob,
  maxWidth: number,
  maxHeight: number,
  scale = 1
): Promise<Blob> {
  return new Promise<Blob>((fulfill, reject) => {
    const image = new Image();

    image.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);

    image.onload = () => {
      URL.revokeObjectURL(image.src);

      const width = image.width;
      const height = image.height;

      if (width <= maxWidth && height <= maxHeight) {
        fulfill(file);
      }

      let newWidth = 0;
      let newHeight = 0;

      if (scale !== 1) {
        newWidth = (width * scale) / maxWidth;
        newHeight = (height * scale) / maxHeight;
      } else if (width > height) {
        newHeight = height * (maxWidth / width);
        newWidth = maxWidth;
      } else {
        newWidth = width * (maxHeight / height);
        newHeight = maxHeight;
      }

      console.log(newWidth, newHeight);

      const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.width = newWidth;
      canvas.height = newHeight;

      const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

      context?.drawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);

      canvas.toBlob((blob) => blob && fulfill(blob), file.type);
    };

    image.onerror = reject;
  });
}
```

And finally, the Resize component:

```
const Resize: React.FC<Props> = ({ actual, setResize, setCustom, custom }) => {
  let stats: Stats = {} as Stats;

  const getStats = useCallback((): Stats => stats, []);

  const updateStats = useCallback(
    (newStats: Stats): Stats => (stats = newStats),
    []
  );

  const getResizedCustom = useCallback(
    async (copy: Custom): Promise<Custom> => {
      const actualWidth = window.innerWidth;
      const actualHeight = window.innerHeight;

      const maxWidth = actualWidth < 1152 ? 180 : 360;
      const maxHeight = actualHeight < 800 ? 180 : 360;

      const newBlob = await resizeImage(
        copy.blob,
        maxWidth,
        maxHeight,
        getStats().scale
      );

      return {
        blob: newBlob,
        img: URL.createObjectURL(newBlob),
        id: copy.id,
        type: 'custom',
        price: copy.price,
        amount: copy.amount,
      };
    },
    [stats]
  );

  const updateActual = useCallback(async () => {
    // remove actual
    const newCustomArr = [...custom];
    const customCopy = newCustomArr.splice(newCustomArr.indexOf(actual), 1)[0];

    const newCustom = await getResizedCustom(customCopy);

    console.log(customCopy);
    console.log(newCustom);
    setCustom([...newCustomArr, newCustom]);
  }, [actual, custom, setCustom, getResizedCustom]);

  return (
    <Container>
      <Header>
        <h1>ADJUST YOUR BRICK</h1>
        <img
          src={close}
          alt='close icon'
          onClick={() => setResize((prev) => !prev)}
        />
      </Header>
      <Main>
        <h2>Pinch and zoom</h2>
        <TransformWrapper onZoomChange={updateStats}>
          <TransformComponent>
            <img src={actual.img} alt='brick' />
          </TransformComponent>
        </TransformWrapper>
        <button
          onClick={async () => (
            await updateActual(), setResize((prev) => !prev)
          )}
        >
          DONE
        </button>
      </Main>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

I'm also using the [react-zoom-pan-pinch](https://github.com/prc5/react-zoom-pan-pinch) to have the ability to zoom in and out the image. My question is: How I could resize the image on the DOM, based on the scale provided by the onZoomChange function from TransformWrapper component? Is that possible? There's a better and less "hacky" way to resize a image on DOM based on a zoom scale?

I'll try to provide a minimum repo soon, but for now, here's the full repo: https://github.com/Mdsp9070/brickart/tree/dev

Answer (score 1):

It is for sure possible, but you need to be passing more props to `drawImage`.  [Check out the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage).  It has four more optional arguments that you're not using.  If you just use the first four then the whole image is included. When using all eight props, the first four refer to what portion of the original image to use (the cropping) while the next four specify where to put that selection of the the image on your canvas.

You need to do some math and some event tracking to calculate the source rectangle based on the center of the zoom and the scale.